# Specific bone not present in the skeleton XNA

Tags: xna, 3dsmax, fbx

I have created a human mesh, bone structure, and animation rig in 3ds max for an XNA game I am developing for school. I am currently having a problem with one specific bone upon build in Visual Studio. It's the 3rd bone of the right pinky and I have promptly named it "The Problem Bone".

[image]

The build is giving me this error:

`Vertex is bound to bone "The Problem Bone", but this bone is not present in the skeleton.`

I've checked the skeleton many times to confirm that the bone does exist. The skeleton hierarchy root is the pelvis bone and I verified that no bone was being ignored due to the mesh having more than one skeleton which is usually the cause of this problem.

After reading the .fbx file, I found that the XNA was building the bones starting with the pelvis, then going down the right leg, then the left leg, then the spine up to the head, and then the right arm which where my problem area is.

[image]

As we can see in the schematic view, the problem bone is linked to a previous successfully built bone.

[image]

The bones are controlled by splines, point helpers, and IK chains through linking and constraining. I don't think that these are the problem since other bones driven by the controllers were successfully built before the problem bone.

So the other bones up until the 3rd bone of the right pinky are being built correctly which gives me the feeling that I'm close to a solution and it's something small impeding my progress.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error?

**Exporting from 3ds Max Process:**

1. Select only the bones and the mesh
2. File > Export > Export Selected
3. Save as .fbx
4. Current .fbx export dialog window

[image]